Jetpack Compose Framework - Android - Kotlin - In a Textfield, why isn't 'query' value being changed once my suspend coroutine is completed?
Short: In my Textfield, why isn't "query" value being cleared once my coroutine is completed?
In my Textfield composable, I am testing a "query" value being passed through a suspend coroutine in order for some mutations to occur. This is in the event of a Type-ahead search for example, where an api endpoint might be called (Dispatchers.IO), and a string value deserialized.
In order for the Textfield to be cleared, the query would be reset to blank once the user has hit 'Send'. While it is possible to clear it within the coroutine scope, which works fine, I am wondering why the value isn't being cleared outside the coroutine eventhough the Job is clearly completed. The job being completed is shown in the simple Text value-change.
The Code:
@Composable
fun Search(){
    val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var changedValue by remember { mutableStateOf("The value is untouched") }
    var query by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var queryThread: Job by remember { mutableStateOf(Job()) }
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center){
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
            TextField(maxLines = 1,
                value = query,
                onValueChange = { query = it },
                modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp)
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester),
                enabled = true,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                    capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words,
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = {
// This is the co-routine, where a value might be mutated

                        queryThread = scope.launch {
                            changedValue = changeValue(query)

                        }
                        keyboard!!.hide()
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
// This would reset the "query" value once the coroutine is completed

                        if (queryThread.isCompleted){
                            query = ""
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
        }
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Text(changedValue, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
        HorizontalDivider(thickness = 10.dp, modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp),
            color = Color.Transparent)
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            val completed = if (queryThread.isCompleted) "Thread has finished running" else "Thread is still running"
            Text(completed, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }
}


suspend fun changeValue(query: String): String{
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = "The value $query passed through a suspend co-routine."
        return@withContext result
    }
}

What I tried and what I was expecting:
I tried clearing the query value once my Job() completed, checking this with a simple conditional statement.
I expected the TextField value to be blank, but the same value was showing instead.
While the job completed fine, the value was not being cleared.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The issue stems from how UI updates are handled with coroutines in Jetpack Compose. Here's why your query value isn't resetting after the coroutine completes:
The Problem:
You're checking the coroutine's completion state (queryThread.isCompleted) inside the onDone callback. However, UI updates in Compose cannot occur directly from within a coroutine. So, even though the coroutine completes and the if statement evaluates as true, the UI doesn't update right away.
You can solve it by using launch with a completion callback to perform the UI update. This callback will be executed on the main thread after the coroutine finishes, allowing you to safely update the UI.
check this code :
TextField(
...
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
    onDone = {
        queryThread = scope.launch {
            changedValue = changeValue(query)
        }.apply {
            invokeOnCompletion {
                query = "" // Clear query after completion
            }
        }
        keyboard!!.hide()
        focusManager.clearFocus()
    }
)
)

Note: this answer is taken from Google Gemini and paraphrased on chat gpt

Thanks to Gemini for the answer, give my regards! I am sorry I cannot give feedback as I have less than 15 questions posted. I tried, but it does not appear, although it tells me my feedback was recorded for their own nefarious purposes.
I was not aware of "invokeOnCompletion" which makes matters considerably easier when co-routines are involved, as it is easier to avoid race conditions without using delegated properties and state.

@PAttah please read the guidelines and make your question straight forward, neat & simple to understand. Thanks & regards!
